$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \delta_{t_i} \right\| = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\alpha_i|$
$t_1, \ldots, t_n \in [0,1]$ pairwise distinct and $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$.
Prove that
$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \delta_{t_i} \right\| = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\alpha_i|$ , $\delta_{t_i} \in \left(C[0,1], \|\| \cdot \|\|_{\infty}\right)^*
$. I have proven that $\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \delta_{t_i} \right\| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\alpha_i|$.I thought that maybe i can find $f \in C[0,1]
$ ,$\|\|f\|\|_{\infty} \leq 1
$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \delta_{t_i}(f) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i f(t_i)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i|
$ but I couldn't proceed with this idea.

Let $\phi:{\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}$ be the function $\phi(x) = \max (1-|t|,0)$. It is continuous, taking values in $[0,1]$, equal to $1$ at $0$ and to zero outside $(-1,1)$. Draw it. Next, we find a function which is a linear combination of shifts of dilations of $\phi$ and will do the job.
Let $N = \lfloor \frac{2}{\min |t_i-t_j|}\rfloor$ and let  $f_N (x) = \sum_{i} \mbox{sgn}(a_i)\phi( N( t-t_i))$. It is again continuous, and the choice of $N$ implies that it takes values in $[-1,1]$, and is equal to $\mbox{sgn}(a_i)$ at $t_i$. Therefore $\sum_{i} a_{i} \delta_{t_i} (f_N) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mbox{sgn}(a_i) = \sum_{i} |a_i|$.

should be $\max(1-|t|,0)$

WLOG we may assume $t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_n.$ If $a_i$ have the same sign take $f=1.$ Otherwise let the function $f$ be defined as $f(t_i)=1$ for $a_i>0,$ $ f(t_i)=-1$ for $a_i<0,$  and extended  piecewise linearly. Then $\|f\|=1$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^na_if(t_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|$$
